# How to calculate only distinct rows using left join?

Tags: mysql, database, join, left-join

This is my query:

```
SELECT buyer_charges_histories.*,
       count(DISTINCT auction_bids.id) AS opportunities_count,
       count(DISTINCT offers.id) AS offers_count,
       count(DISTINCT orders.id) AS orders_count,
       count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN orders.status_id = 1 THEN orders.id ELSE NULL END) AS pending_orders_count,
       count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN orders.status_id = 3 THEN orders.id ELSE NULL END) AS completed_orders_count,
       count(DISTINCT CASE WHEN orders.status_id = 5 THEN orders.id ELSE NULL END) AS canceled_orders_count,
       sum(CASE WHEN orders.status_id = 3 THEN orders.seller_payout ELSE NULL END) as seller_payout
FROM `buyer_charges_histories`
LEFT JOIN `quotes` ON `quotes`.`buyer_charges_history_id` = `buyer_charges_histories`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `offers` ON `quotes`.`id` = `offers`.`quote_id`
AND `offers`.`draft` = 0
AND (`offers`.`enterprise` = 0
     OR `offers`.`enterprise` IS NULL)
LEFT JOIN `auction_bids` ON `offers`.`auction_id` = `auction_bids`.`auction_id`
LEFT JOIN `orders` ON `offers`.`order_id` = `orders`.`id`
AND `orders`.`test` IS NULL
WHERE `buyer_charges_histories`.`buyer_id` = 1
  AND `buyer_charges_histories`.`buyer_id` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `buyer_charges_histories`.`id`
ORDER BY `buyer_charges_histories`.`id` DESC
```

`seller_payout` returns wrong value as obviously it counts duplicate rows. I confirmed this using the following query:

```
select sum(seller_payout) from orders where exists (
    select * from offers where offers.order_id = orders.id and offers.draft = 0 and (offers.enterprise = 0 or offers.enterprise is null) and exists (
        select * from quotes where quotes.id = offers.quote_id and quotes.buyer_charges_history_id = 136
    )
) and test is null and status_id = 3
```

How do I only sum distinct orders rows?

Comment: Aggregate in subquery then join.

Comment: ' obviously it counts duplicate rows - is it - sample data would confirm.

Comment: @Akina Can you show me an example?

Comment: @P.Salmon View my updated question. Cannot provide a sample data right now but I have added the query that I used to verify my claim.

Comment: Trying to answer your question, I realize you haven't explained how to get a correct `seller_payout` for a particular single `buyer_charges_histories.id` value. It requires diving into a sequence of 1::many relationships `buyer_charges_histories`::`quotes`::`offers`::`auction_bids`::`orders`.  When you join all those together you get a combinatorial explosion to feed into your GROUP BY. Please [edit] your question to show more information. `COUNT(DISTINCT something)` hides most of this explosion, but `SUM(something)` can't do that.

Answer (score 1):

You have some issues with the condition placement in the query. It did not include additional conditions for offers and orders tables in the join clauses. These conditions should be included in the respective join conditions instead of the WHERE clause to ensure the left join semantics are preserved.

```
SELECT buyer_charges_histories.*,
       COUNT(DISTINCT auction_bids.id) AS opportunities_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT offers.id) AS offers_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT orders.id) AS orders_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN orders.status_id = 1 THEN orders.id END) AS pending_orders_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN orders.status_id = 3 THEN orders.id END) AS completed_orders_count,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN orders.status_id = 5 THEN orders.id END) AS canceled_orders_count,
       SUM(CASE WHEN orders.status_id = 3 THEN orders.seller_payout END) AS seller_payout
FROM buyer_charges_histories
LEFT JOIN quotes ON quotes.buyer_charges_history_id = buyer_charges_histories.id
LEFT JOIN offers ON quotes.id = offers.quote_id
LEFT JOIN auction_bids ON offers.auction_id = auction_bids.auction_id
LEFT JOIN orders ON offers.order_id = orders.id
WHERE buyer_charges_histories.buyer_id = 1
  AND buyer_charges_histories.buyer_id IS NOT NULL
  AND (offers.draft = 0 OR offers.draft IS NULL)
  AND (offers.enterprise = 0 OR offers.enterprise IS NULL)
  AND orders.test IS NULL
GROUP BY buyer_charges_histories.id
ORDER BY buyer_charges_histories.id DESC
```

Try this and let me know if it works fine